# How to calculate this matrix in component-form? (Undergrad)

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, inverse-problems

If ${A}_{ab} = \delta_{ab} + \varepsilon_{abc}n^c$ and $B^{ab} = \frac{1}{1+n^2}(\delta^{ab} + n^an^b - \varepsilon^{abc}n_c)$ what is the correct way to evaluate
$$C^{ab} = (AB)^{ab} $$

Here, $\delta_{ab}$ is the Kronecker symbol, $n$ is a vector and $\varepsilon$ is the totally anti-symmetric unit tensor.

Comment: What do your notations mean? Is $\delta_{ab}$ a *matrix*? If so, what is it? Also, what is $n$? This is a very confuzing question.

Comment: Hello, $\delta_{ab}$ is the Kronecker delta symbol so when such that $\delta_{ab}=1$ only when $a=b$. $n$ is a vector. Does this help?

Comment: So you are saying that $\delta_{ab}$ is a *scalar*, not a matrix. How is $A_{ab}$ then a matrix? And you didn't tell me what $\epsilon_{abc}$ is, nor what $n$ is, nor what $a,b$ and $c$ are. Edit your question. Then read it. Then ask yourself if there is anything unclear about it.

Comment: No, $\delta_{ab}$ is a component of a matrix, namely the unit matrix. $\varepsilon$ is the totally anti-symmetric unit tensor and $a,b,c$ are indices. $A_{ab}$ denotes the component $a,b$ of the matrix A. I dont think my question need modification since this is standard linear algebra, right?

Comment: As a person with a masters in mathematics, I am pretty confident in saying this is not standard notation for linear algebra. The "unit matrix?" Does that mean the Idendity matrix?

Comment: Identity matrix = unity matrix. Sorry, but in every undergrad book I have see this is standard. Maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the point of this exercise was for you utilize the properties of the Levi-Civita tensor $\varepsilon$ to discover that 
$$
 C^{ab} = \delta^{ab}
$$
For convenience, let $N = \varepsilon \cdot n$ which is a skew-symmetric second order tensor, and $s = 1 + n^2$ which is a scalar.  Then 
$$ \eqalign {
A &= I + N \cr
sB &=  I + nn - N \cr
} $$
Their product is
$$ \eqalign {
sA\cdot B &= (I + N)\cdot(I + nn - N) \cr
 &=  (I + nn - N) + (N + N\cdot nn - N^2) \cr
 &=  I + nn - N^2 \cr
 &=  I + nn - (nn-n^2 I) \cr
 &=  I + n^2 I \cr
 &=  sI \cr
} $$
In the preceding, I used the fact that $N\cdot n = \varepsilon : nn = 0$, since $nn$ is symmetric and $\varepsilon$ is skew in all indices. I'll leave it to you to confirm that $N^2 = (nn-n^2I)$ for which [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2) should be helpful.